# What episode of The Expanse shows how the poor in New York City live?

Tags: episode-identification, the-expanse-2015

This episode showed what appeared to be homeless people just scraping by in New York City.  Any idea which episode this was?  It was season 1 or 2.

Comment: I've downvoted due to the lack of research effort. The Expanse has so few episodes that scrolling through the list in the wiki would reveal the answer in seconds.

Comment: And if you are aware of this wiki you're alluding to?

Comment: Then you'd just scroll through the list for something like 10 seconds and find the episode, hence the lack of research effort I mentioned. Btw, this is the wiki: http://expanse.wikia.com/wiki/The_Expanse_(TV)

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "unaware".  If a person doesn't don't know about the wiki, is downvoting their question the appropriate response?

Comment: The point was the lack of research, ie making at least a basic Google search like "the Expanse series episodes", which would reveal the answer in seconds ;)

Comment: What is the point of creating a resource people can use to find answers if they are supposed to find the answers before they use the resource?  I did plenty of google searches to figure this out, by the way.  And yes I found lists of episodes.  Not with all of the scenes described right in the list, so not sure how I would discover what was in each episode.

Comment: The point is that, as with everything in life, you should do a minimal amount of research yourself before asking the experts. Don't take my comments the wrong way, I am only trying to help as being better prepared in the future, will help you ask better questions and more importantly get better answers. Cheers!

Comment: I did plenty of research.  In any case, there's nothing wrong with asking a question even if you haven't.

Comment: "there's nothing wrong with asking a question even if you haven't" My professors at the university think otherwise :P

Answer (score 7):

Season 2, Episode 10, Bobbie Draper sneaks out of the Martian Embassy and goes to find the ocean, which she has never seen.  On the way she gets lost and finds herself among the poor.

[image: On the mean streets of the Big Apple]
Bobbie freaks out, and is calmed by one of the New Yorkers
[image: Bobbie freaks out, and is calmed by one of the New Yorkers]

Comment: Not the exact scene I was thinking of but similar.